# How can I filter my datasource using checkboxes using Angular Material?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to `filter my datatable` by clicking a `checkbox`. Checking one checkbox filters it properly, but `checking multiple` is the `problem`.

The `Angular Material documentation` is very vague regarding proper filtering where a lot of elements are involved. It has something to do with `filterPredicate`, but there is almost no (or just awfully vague) online documentation.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
              <mat-label>Select Province(s)</mat-label>
              <mat-select placeholder='Provinces' formControlName="provinceSelector" multiple>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let p of provinces" [value]='p.provinceName' (click)='addfilter()'>
                  {{p.provinceName}} ({{p.adsInProvince}})
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

```js
this.registeredUserService.GetAllAdverts().subscribe(val => {

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Card>(val);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
const myPredicate = (myObject:IProvince,filterString:any)=>
      {
        let filterObj:IProvince = JSON.parse(filterString);
        if(!filterObj.provinceName.includes((obj)=>obj=myObject.provinceName))
        {
          return false;
        }
        else
        {return true;}
      }
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate=myPredicate;

myFilter:IProvince={
    provinceName:[]
  }
  addfilter() {
    this.myFilter.provinceName=this.search.value;
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.myFilter);
  }

export interface Card {
  advertDate: any;
  advertDescription: any;
  advertID: any;
  cityName: any;
  provinceName: any;
  sellerID: any;
  sellingPrice: any;
  vehicleColor: any;
  vehicleMake: any;
  vehicleMileage: any;
  vehicleModel: any;
  vehicleYear: any;
}
export interface IProvince{
  provinceName:any[];
}
```

it should just filter through the selected values...

it does not do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are right with the filter predicate. You can define how to filter you dataSource. It is a function which returns true(if filter matches) or false.

```
const myPredicate = (myObject, filterString) => {
  let filterObj: MyFilterObj = JSON.parse(filterString);
  if(!filterObj.attributeA.find((obj) => obj == myObject.name) ||myObject.attributeB != filterObject.attributeB) { // <-- edit includes to find
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Put the following code after generating your `MatTableDataSource`:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.myPredicate.
```

Use the following method for setting your filter. I always give a type string for determining which filter I want to set.

```
myFilter: MyFilterObject = {   // <-- define this variable in your ngOnInit method
  attributeA: [], // <-- this is the place where you can put your selected options
  attributeB: null
}

applyFilter(value: any, type: string) {
  switch(type) {
    case "attributeA":
       this.myFilter.attributeA = value;
       break;
     case "attributeB":
       this.myFilter.attributeB = value;
       break;
     default:
       break;
  }
  this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.myFilter);
}
```

Comment: what would you do if you are selecting multiple values from a select and want it to filter only the values that are selected (checked)?
I updated my code

Comment: should every selected value be matched or only a minimum of one?

Comment: the filtering should only cater for that that has been selected
eg. a select contains Arizona, New York, and California
And I select california and Arizona, it should only filter those two states

Comment: It returned an error `filterObj.provinceName.includes is not a function
    at MatTableDataSource.myPredicate`. I updated the code once again :(

Comment: try to change `includes` to `find`. I would also suggest to set the value of you filter on `selectionChange` of your mat select. `<mat-select (selectionChange)="applyFilter($event.value, 'attributeA')">`. You can also debug an look if your `attributeA` exists or not. If nothing of this works pls set up a stackblitz project and share it so that we can help you easier.